# Mule Untilsuccessful failure expression not working

Tags: mule

I have given my until successful as below, but still even though i get a 200 response it is trying to call the flow "test" back again.

```
<until-successful maxRetries="2" millisBetweenRetries="1500" failureExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200 or 202 or 500]" synchronous="true" doc:name="Until Successful">
  <flow-ref name="test" doc:name="test"/>
</until-successful>
```

If I give only one code in this way it is working fine

```
<until-successful maxRetries="2" millisBetweenRetries="1500" failureExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200]" synchronous="true" doc:name="Until Successful">
      <flow-ref name="test" doc:name="test"/>

</until-successful>
```

I've tried giving the expression as follows too, but not working

```
failureExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200 || message.inboundProperties['http.status'] !=202]"
```

Can someone please help me with the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your expression says Status != 200 || Status != 202
that means in case of status = 200 you fail second condition and in case of status = 202 you fail first condition

what you could do is to define: fail is when Status != 200 AND Status !=202 AND Status !=500

```
failureExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200 && #[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 202 && #[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 500]"
```

Comment: It worked if we write in this way failureExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200 && message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 202 && message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 500]"